# Characterization of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let’s assume $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of p-adic integers. Then, how can we determine the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ as an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, when it is defined? More specifically, I want to show that any p-adic integer with periodic p-adic expansion belongs to $\mathbb{Q}$, but it is not clear for me what I should show.

Comment: for your more specific question you just need to sum a geometric series (that's what a periodic number, in the end, is) and get a rational number

Comment: @user8268 My main question actually is that why it is working?

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? Is it that you don't see why a "periodic number" is a geometric series? Is it that you don't see why the usual formula for the sum of a geometric series works in the $p$-adics? Is it that you don't see why the formula for the sum of a geometric series gives a rational number?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, many thanks for your comment. It is because I do not see why the usual formula for the geometric series works in p-adics and also I do not see what is an element of Q in p-adics.

Comment: The proof of the formula for the sum of a geometric series in the $p$-adics is exactly the same as the proof in the reals. Try it, and see! (or report back as to where you see a difficulty). And an element of the rationals is just a quotient of two integers, as always. I'm still not sure I understand where the difficulty is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ohh. Fir the geometric series, then what is the definition of convergence? And for the other one, I can not see the meaning of a p-adic integer being a rational number. These are two different rings, I guess we can talk about this if we know there is a common extention of both.

Comment: The definition of convergence is exactly as it is in the reals, only with the $p$-adic absolute value instead of the absolute value we use on the reals. For the other, maybe it would be better if I said that the $p$-adics have a subfield isomorphic to the rationals.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3876767/96384

Comment: Are we OK now, Pouya?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$G = \{ \sum_{n\ge -N} a_n p^n \in \Bbb{Q}_p, a_n\in 0\ldots p-1,\exists m,k, \forall n\ge m, a_n= a_{n+k}\}$$

- Show it is a group using finiteness of states during carry calculations in $\sum_{n\ge -N} a_n p^n-\sum_{n\ge -N} b_n p^n$
- For $s=p^{-N} u/v\in \Bbb{Q}, p\nmid v$ let $r$ be the order of $p\bmod v$ then  $$s=p^{-N} \frac{w}{1-p^r}= w p^{-N}\sum_{n\ge 0} p^{rn}\in  wG\subset G$$
- Conversely if $\sum_{n\ge -N} a_n p^n\in G$ then $$\sum_{n\ge -N} a_n p^n=\sum_{n=-N}^{km-1} a_n p^n + \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} a_l \sum_{n=0}^\infty p^{l+kn+km}=\sum_{n=-N}^{km-1} a_n p^n + \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} a_l\frac{p^{l+km}}{1-p^k}\in \Bbb{Q}$$